# Number of Open SQL Connection allow on one application pool?

Tags: sql-server, iis, application-pool

Number of Open SQL Connection allow on one application pool? If we have deployed multiple websites and concurrently there are lot of open connections for these websites, do we have any limit on application level or we just set max pool size on website connection string?

Basically, I'm getting an error:

> The timeout expired. The timeout expired prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. Because it reached its max pool size.

Comment: The default max pool size is 100 and adequate for most needs. Although this can be increased via the connection string with SqlClient, I suggest you first identify the root cause, which could be long-running queries in need of query/index tuning, long-term blocking, not closing connections properly in code, etc.

Comment: ok, but currently our application pool have multiple websites and we are having concurrently connection opens request.I have checked we are closing correctly all connections from code side.
But may be due to heavy traffic and multiple website on single application pool it was affecting.

Comment: The symptoms may also be due to an overloaded app server or database server. You could increase the connection timeout (default is 15 seconds) to avoid the error during peaks but it would be best to address root cause. Note there is a separate connection pool for each unique connection string.

Comment: The Dan's last sentence should be bolded, although there are no such possibilities in writing comments. If the connection string is not an EXACT MATCH to an existing pool, a new pool is created. Connections are pooled per process, per application domain, per connection string and when integrated security is used, per Windows identity. Connection strings must also be an EXACT MATCH; keywords supplied in a different order for the same connection will be pooled separately.

Comment: Have you tried to expand max pool size in your connection string? The only restriction is default value=100.

Comment: Yes, I have increase pool size from 100 to 5000, but it fails after some time, I figure it out there one place in my code, connection is not closing properly.